# Optimization Perl script

Tags: perl, optimization, cgi

Is it possible to make this script faster ?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
    use strict;
    use CGI;
    package SwitchGUI;

    sub new {
        my ($classe, $nom, $nbports, $gio) = @_;

        my $this = {
            "nom"     => $nom,
            "nbports" => $nbports,
            "gio"     => $gio
        };

        bless($this, $classe);
        $this->afficher();
        return $this;   
    }

    sub afficher {
        my ($this) = @_;
        my @tab = ( 1 .. $this->{nbports} );
        my @odd = grep { $_ % 2 } @tab;
        my @even = grep { not $_ % 2 } @tab;

        my $cgi = new CGI;
        my $i;
        my $j;

        print "<div id=\"$this->{nom}\" class=\"switch\">\n";
        print $cgi->h2("$this->{nom}");

        print "<div class=\"ports\">";
        for my $port (@odd) {
            my $res = `perl ifname-index.pl -h $this->{nom} -i FastEthernet0/$port -c reseau`;

            if ($res =~ /^Erreur /) {
                print $cgi->img({
                src => 'ressources/interface_haut_down.png',  
                alt => "port n°$port",
                }), "\n",
            }
            else {
                print $cgi->a({class=>"tooltip", title=>$res},$cgi->img({
                src => 'ressources/interface_haut_up.png',  
                alt => "port n°$port",
                }), "\n",)
            }
        }

        print "<br/>";
        for my $port (@even) {
            my $res = `perl ifname-index.pl -h $this->{nom} -i FastEthernet0/$port -c reseau`;      
            if ($res =~ /^Erreur/) {
                print $cgi->img({
                src => 'ressources/interface_bas_down.png',  
                alt => "port n°$port",
                }), "\n",
            }
            else {
                if ($this->getDuplex($res)!="Full") {
                    print $cgi->a({class=>"tooltip", title=>$res},$cgi->img({
                    src => 'ressources/interface_bas_duplex.png',  
                    alt => "port n°$port",
                    }), "\n",)
                }
                elsif ($this->getVitesse($res)!="100"){
                    print $cgi->a({class=>"tooltip", title=>$res},$cgi->img({
                    src => 'ressources/interface_bas_speed.png',  
                    alt => "port n°$port",
                    }), "\n",)
                }
                else {
                    print $cgi->a({class=>"tooltip", title=>$res},$cgi->img({
                    src => 'ressources/interface_bas_up.png',  
                    alt => "port n°$port",
                    }), "\n",)
                }
            }
        }
        print "</div>";
        print "<div class=\"gio\">";
        for ($j=0;$j<$this->{gio};$j++) {
            my $req = system("perl ifname-index.pl -h $this->{nom} -i GigabitEthernet0/$j -c reseau &");
            print $cgi->img({
                src => 'ressources/interface_bas_down.png',  
                alt => "port",
                });
        }
        print "</div>\n";

        print "</div>\n";

    }

    1;
```

It executes a perl script (which uses SNMP to query network equipment), and depending of the return of this script, it displays an appropriate image and description.  This script is used for ajax call, from another cgi script.

My question is: **can I execute multiple script by adding `&` or something similar

 at the end of the following line?**

```
my $res = `perl ifname-index.pl -h $this->{nom} -i FastEthernet0/$port -c reseau`;
```

Comment: It is definitely possible to get that faster. Persistent execution will help tremendously, and as mentioned by jomo666, calling perl in the shell is another performance hit. Rewriting this probably isn't trivial enough for an answer here. :{ Look to [Plack](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Plack) for persistent deployment help, even with CGI. Sidenote: if you have non-ASCII in your script like `port n°$port` then you should `use utf8` at the top.

Comment: @Ashley : Ok, looking at it, thanks for help. I ask you more precise question maybe :)

Comment: @Ashley : By persistent execution and Plack, do you mean writing my script to subroutines ? And use Parallel::Jobs or similar to execute them simultanously ?

Comment: no, I meant one of the Plack deployment servers. I should have linked some. These are worth looking at [plackup](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?plackup), [starman](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?starman), [twiggy](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?twiggy). That way your CGI (or whatever code you end up with) can be loaded/compiled once and executed on demand. This won't solve/help the external call issues for SNMP stuff unless you also rewrite that to avoid the shell.

Answer (score 7):

While i don't want comment much things like using CGI and "print" (in 2011 is *really* archaic), I will comment two lines:

```
my $res = `perl ifname-index.pl -h $this->{nom} -i FastEthernet0/$port -c reseau`;
...
my $req = system("perl ifname-index.pl -h $this->{nom} -i GigabitEthernet0/$j -c reseau &");
```

Starting another perl-processes really slowing speed down.
You're making package for displaying HTML, but not for polling?

Re-factor `ifname-index.pl` to subroutine. So,

```
my $res = get_request_interface(name => $this->{nom}, interface => "FastEthernet0/$port");
```

or to an package (the right way) - something like...

```
my $interface = My::Interface::Handler->new();
my $res = $interface->get_request;
...
my $another_result = $interface->get_request;
#etc
```

And ofc, **it is possible** start more (multiple) processes and communicate with them, but the solution will be probably more complicated than refactoring ifname-index.pl to subroutine. (read this: [How do I start a process in the background?](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq8#How-do-I-start-a-process-in-the-background?))

Summarization for a "cool" app - based on comments:

- build a web page where you list the interfaces, for example N-status lines for N ports
- the page will send N ajax (parallel) requests to the server for the status with javascript
- the server will execute N parallel SNMP requests, and send N ajax responses
- the page will get responses from the server and update the correct divs

With above way:

- the user get immediately an web page
- the page has a feedback for user - "wait, i'm working on getting status"
- the server executing N parallel requests to snmp
- ajax responses updating the page as they come from the server

For the web part is the best to use PGSI-type server. Check CPAN, several one exists.
`Tatsuhiko Miyagawa` **is** "The Perl Hero" for these days :)

Ps:

- http://www.perlcritic.org
- http://onyxneon.com/books/modern_perl/

Comment: @jomo666 : I used some `print` in my script, because didn't know how to imbric multiple div, etc...  Ok, I see what you mean by refactoring ifname-indexd.pl    Have you got synonym for poll ? Don't know what it means...

Comment: check: CPAN module Net::SNMP.

Comment: @jomo666 : That's the module I use to request switches via SNMP.

Comment: @jomo666 : Do i refactor ifname-index.pl to module.pm ? And I write a constrcutor, methods... ? And I use parallel jobs to run several methods in same time ? I don't understand `my $res = get_request_interface(name => $this->{nom}...` Why not `module->new(name =>... );`

Comment: @jomo666 : Ok, thanks, I try to rewrite ifname-index.pl to package mode. And after I will be easier to use parallel jobs (or multiple thread, or other module) to run SwitchGUI faster ?

Comment: you may send parallel (non-blocking) requests. Check examples for non-blocking requests in http://search.cpan.org/~dtown/Net-SNMP-v6.0.1/lib/Net/SNMP.pm#EXAMPLES